# How do you add the cmd+backspace functionality on VSCode's Integrated Terminal to the Mac's

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, terminal, command-line-interface

I've been dying to get this working on the default terminal on the mac, this feature is really useful when you write something wrong, and can just cmd + backspace to delete all the lines.

I googled online several times but I couldn't find anything related to this.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the functionality is already there: <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> will delete everything left to your cursor to the beginning of the line. You cannot, however, change this keyboard shortcut.

You can change application-specific keybindings by installing additional tools like, for example, [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/).

Alternatively, you can install [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/) as a Terminal replacement. That will allow you to enable this - and many other text editing keybindings - with one click in the settings.